# Buffer gets with execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, buffer, execution-time

I'd like to ask about the buffer gets meaning. With the reduction of buffer gets then I can assume that I've reduced the I/O needed, but can I also say that it has something to do with the execution time too?
Mostly I found that with reduced buffer gets it has an impact with reduction execution time, but in a few case it showed that I have also a reduced execution time eventhough my buffer gets increase. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance!

PS : I'm using Oracle 11g RDBMS

Comment: Why the obsession over buffer gets?

Comment: Well I guess I just want to prove that my thought is right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reduction in buffer gets generally but does not always correlate to a faster runtime.  There is definitely a correlation but the correlation is not perfect.

A buffer get will take vastly different amounts of time depending on whether the database can simply pull the block from the SGA cache, whether it can be read from the file system cache, whether it can be read from the SAN cache, or whether it actually requires a physical read.  And the time required to do a physical read is highly dependent on how your SAN is structured and whether it stores different blocks on faster or slower disks.  In many modern SANs, you may have a small amount of solid state disk for the most frequently read blocks, some fast hard drives for commonly read blocks, and slower hard drives for the less commonly read blocks each with their own performance characteristics.

It is entirely possible that you could reduce the amount of logical I/O that your query does but change the nature of the I/O so that it is more likely to be cached.  If, for example, you have a nested loop where you are constantly doing an index scan, it is relatively likely that a large portion of the index is going to get cached in the SGA relatively quickly meaning that most of the logical I/O you do on that index ends up being satisfied by relatively fast buffer gets that only have to grab the block from the SGA.  An alternate plan that involves, say, doing a full table scan, might do less logical I/O but, since relatively few blocks from the table are likely to be cached, most of that I/O might require physical reads.  It is entirely possible that, in this sort of situation, the query plan that does more logical I/O would complete more quickly.

In practice, though, it is relatively rare that a human is going to be able to accurately predict which buffer gets are likely to require physical reads and which will generally be serviced from cache.  Your non-production environments almost certainly don't have the same pattern of cache utilization that your production environments have since you're not running the same sort of workload in those environments.  Even on the production system, the set of blocks that is cached varies tremendously over the course of a day and human developers rarely have reason to know or understand those variations.  So just because when you're testing a query you find that it does more buffer gets but runs more quickly than an equivalent query, that may not indicate that you'll see a similar pattern in production.  Since the number of buffer gets is (more or less) equivalent across environments (assuming more or less equivalent data volumes), it is generally much easier in practice to focus on reducing logical I/O and let Oracle take care of the rest.

Additionally, queries wait on much more than just I/O.  Queries wait on CPU, they wait on network events, they wait on locks and latches and other serialization devices.  Buffer gets measures just I/O, it doesn't attempt to account for any of those other types of waits.  So you can also have situations where one plan does substantially less I/O but waits substantially longer on CPU or network or RAC cache fusion or some other event so that its execution time is much larger despite spending much less time waiting on I/O.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! So in conclusion, I can't keep the mindset that with increased buffer gets, the execution time SHOULD increase too. Right? And then I can say that after what I encountered this rare ocassion ( buffer increase, exe time decrease ) it's somehow possible, yes?

Comment: @RedFux227 - It is perfectly reasonable to expect that, generally, decreasing the number of buffer gets will decrease execution time.  It is not reasonable to expect that **every** decrease in the number of buffer gets will decrease execution time.  There is a strong correlation but it is not perfect.

Comment: So If I get asked by let's say my supervisor about why buffer gets increased but execution time decreased, what is the best summary answer to explain that?

Comment: @RedFux227 - That's what my answer is discussing.  There are a number of possible explanations but I go over the most common explanations in my answer.

Comment: So, what If I sum it like this : that buffer gets is more focused onto I/O or resources the system needed and execution time is more focused onto how long to get the query generated so  it's great if both of them was reduced after the tuning process but somehow it's also alright if one of them isn't reduced.  In the end I can somehow say "well, the time is reduced but unfortunately the resources it needed is increased". Am I right with that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RedFux227 - I would summarize it as "not all buffer gets require the same amount of runtime and not all the waits for a query are due to I/O"

Comment: so I can explain that "execution time is more related to the time needed for the query to be generated meanwhile buffer gets is more to the resources needed, if there's a differentiation (one of them increase, one of them decrease) between both of them it's not a problem but it's better if both of them was reduced".  Correct?

Comment: @RedFux227 - I'm not sure what "generated" means in this context-- that is not a technical term.  Buffer gets is a measure of logical I/O.  Logical I/O is one component of the time that is required to execute a query.  CPU utilization, network traffic, RAC interconnect waits, etc. are other components of execution time that are not at all related to buffer gets.  Even if we ignore those other components of execution time, different buffer gets require different amounts of time due to caching.

Comment: So, the basic concept is buffer decreased = execution time decreased. But let's say we ignore all those components you previously told but buffer gets. I can specifically explain that if in 1 query I found increase amount of buffer gets but reduced time of execution, and in the same query ( with slightly different syntax because of the tuning ) I found that execution time is increased while buffer gets is decreased, that difference is probably because of some caching process in the buffer, right?

Comment: @RedFux227 - Yes.  If we assume the other wait events are unchanged, the difference is likely to be because of caching.

Comment: Well thank you for the answers! You've been such a great help!

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to ask. About the caching process. Big amount of buffer gets could have a caching process that works faster than low amount of caching process could be slower. Is that somehow because of the data structure from my query?

Comment: @RedFux227 - It is possible, sure. That's what I was talking about in my answer with the nested loop index scan vs the table scan. It's also possible, of course, that the difference is exclusively down to what happens to be in cache at any point in time-- particularly if you've been trying different variants of a query that causes more of the blocks that you happen to be interested in to be cached as time goes by.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Anyway, with the reduction of buffer gets is that also mean I reduce the space required to be put onto memory?

Comment: @RedFux227 - I'm not sure what "the space required to be put onto memory" means.  If you are asking whether reducing the number of buffer gets will reduce the amount of RAM the session consumes, that is generally not the case.

Comment: I thought that by reducing it then the memory could save up some space for other buffers to be put. So what exactly the benefit of having buffer gets decreased?